# I am confused about a present perfect tense

Tags: present-perfect, passive-voice

Which one is correct in below sentence; I am confuse about "**been**".

> 1) You have been disconnected from black ops 2 server.
>
> 2) You have disconnected from black ops 2 server.

Comment: First one is correct

Comment: No, either one is correct. It depends on (wait for it...) the context and communicative function of the sentence.

Comment: In general, the first sentence means something or someone other than you did the disconnecting. The second is a confirmation that you yourself disconnected.

Comment: @AlanCarmack That's a good enough answer for me, actually. ;-)

Comment: Perhaps @DamkerngT   but if I'd the time to write an answer, I'd explain what *been* is doing there.

Comment: @AlanCarmack: That's a [very unusual contraction](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=if+I%27d+the+time%2Cif+I+had+the+time&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cif%20I%20had%20the%20time%3B%2Cc0).

Answer (score 6):

The difference is simply that the "passive voice" version *You have **been** disconnected [from some server]* means *someone or something **else*** (not ***you***) was responsible for the disconnection.

Active voice *You have disconnected* means *the person being addressed* did the disconnecting.

---

It's worth covering a couple of points raised in comments by @Ustanak and @ruakh below...

- Present Perfect is used rather than Simple Past (Passive: *You were disconnected*; Active: *You disconnected*) because the action in the past (regardless of who did the disconnecting) has relevance to the current situation (the fact that the addressee has no connection *now*).
- It just so happens that in OP's exact context either the "speaker" (server connection management software?) or the addressee (logged on remote user?) could have initiated the disconnection. But even if it was actually *you the user* who decided to break the connection, the software might reasonably confirm having carried out your instructions using the passive voice.
  Thus the "subject" of the verb ***to disconnect*** is somewhat ambiguous. There's no such ambiguity with, say, *You (subject = "agent") **have chosen*** | *You (object = "patient") **have been chosen***.

Comment: I'm wondering why you changed the tenses when you explained. In light of the given tense in the sentences, I would've written *someone or something has been responsible for* and *the person being addressed has done the disconnecting*, or it doesn't just matter?

Comment: +1. Note that, in some cases, the difference is just a matter of perspective, rather than a factual distinction. For example, if you type the `exit` command to have the server close your connection, then "You have disconnected" and "You have been disconnected" are both correct, but denote slightly different aspects of the event.

Comment: @Ustanak: It's idiomatic to use *you have been cut off* rather than simple past *You **were** cut off* (or the even more unidiomatic *You **are** cut off*). That's because the statement is *explaining why / pointing out that* you're not connected ***right now***, and Present Perfect is all about making a link between the past act of disconnecting and present state of being disconnected. But using it in my "active" rephrasing is at best unnecessary, and at worst it just sounds kinda weird. I can't imagine a context where you'd want to phrase things like that.

Comment: @ruakh: I'm not sure that's a *syntactic* issue - it's a matter of the *semantics* of the verb ***to disconnect***. We're probably dealing with a "control" system that's actually capable of doing the disconnection itself (as well as issuing informative messages about what's going on! :) If we switch to a different verb where there can be no such ambiguity, there's no mistaking the different subjects/agents in *You have been chosen* vs *You have chosen*. I think that's the essential issue being covered here.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: Oh, definitely; I don't mean to suggest otherwise. But the OP is asking which of two specific sentences is correct, so I thought it worth pointing out that in some cases, *both* are correct. (Your answer otherwise could be taken to imply that the two are mutually exclusive, with only #1 being correct in some cases and only #2 being correct in all others.)

Comment: @ruakh: Point taken. I'll edit the answer accordingly.

Comment: I have not satisfied with this answer yet. please explain it little bit more.

Comment: @rajiv Dixit: You'll have to tell me *what* you don't understand. Do you get the difference between ***You chose*** (you selected something you wanted) and ***You were chosen*** (someone else selected you for some purpose), for example?

Comment: Brother can you tell me how to use been exactly in sentences. please give some example where you use been in sentence for example in present perfect. i know this is not my question  but i need help if you can. i would be happy

Comment: @rajiv Dixit: Again, do you understand the difference in meaning between ***You chose*** and ***You were chosen*** (Simple Past, active and passive)? The Present Perfect versions of those two statements (***You have chosen*** and ***You have been chosen***) mean almost exactly the same as their Simple Past equivalents - it's just that they both imply a closer connection between your current state and the choice (made by you ***or*** someone else) made in the past.